# facebook like button overlaps other links on IOS

Tags: html, css, facebook

Somehow the implementation of the fb-like button seems to overlap links which are on the right site of the button.

It workes perfectly on windows, but on any mobile device the links which are positioned next to the button are not clickable.

Here is the link : http://www.findix.de

Thank you for any hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this css style:

```
#fx_header *{
 width:79px !important;
}
```

Comment: That completely messes up the header of his website.

Comment: Thank you. That fixed it! 
#fx_header .fb-like{
 position:absolute;
 left:690px;
 margin-top:7px;
 width:75px!important; 
 height:21px !important
}